# Words rhyming with "ear" pronounced with the vowel as in "eat"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

For words like *ear*, *year*, *hear* etc., most dictionaries only give the pronunciation `/-ɪr/` (with the vowel as in the word *it*). But I think some native speakers pronounce them `/-ir/` (with the vowel as in the word *eat*).

Is my observation correct? If so, are both pronunciations acceptable, and what is the difference between them? Are they specific for any dialects?

Comment: In general American English, and in fact in most American dialects, they are two different ways of pronouncing the same phoneme. There are no words which are distinguished by /-ɪr/ in one and  /-ir/ in the other. Some people use one pronunciation, some people use the other, and some people might even use /-ɪr/ before vowels and /-ir/ before consonants.

Comment: relevant: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72065/eer-vowel-accent-dialect-variation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the phoneme /r/, the English contrast between lax and tense vowels is neutralized.
That means no English words exist that distinguish lax /ɪr, ɛr, ɔr, ʊr/ from tense /ir, er, or, ur/.

This varies in many dialects; in Rhode Island (and many other NE N.Am locations), for instance,
speakers distinguish the words *Mary* /'meri/, *merry* /'mɛri/, and *marry* /'mæri/; but in the
Midwest all three words are pronounced /'mɛri/.

In practical terms, anticipating the /r/ in *hear* changes the vowel to something that is different from both the normal tense and the normal lax vowel, and the same thing happens to *beer*.
Native speakers normally can't tell the difference. 
That's what "neutralization" means.

Comment: "Neutralization" doesn't mean that native speakers normally can't tell the difference.

Comment: But in this case, many native speakers **don't** hear the difference.